# How to clone an AWS EMR cluster in command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have a recurring task where I need to clone an existing EMR cluster (except with a different name). I have been doing this in the AWS Console (basically, finding the EMR cluster in the console, click "Clone", change the name, then "Create cluster"). Is there a way to do this in command line so that I can automate it? I have checked `aws emr create-cluster help` but nothing seems relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

[image: Check the image]

Comment: This is helpful, but I think this means there is no 'clone' option in the CLI. My use case requires cloning a cluster that I know the ID of, and I can't find it in the console because of the 10k+ terminated instances I need to page through every time I search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the cluster to be a clone of the starting state of the original cluster, just create the first EMR cluster from a [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) template and then create new clusters from the same template as needed. Here's an [example template](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/EMR/EMRCLusterGangliaWithSparkOrS3backedHbase.json).

Answer (score 0):

**Cloning a Cluster Using the Console**

You can use the Amazon EMR console to clone a cluster, which makes a copy of the configuration of the original cluster to use as the basis for a new cluster.

**To clone a cluster using the console**

- From the Cluster List page, click a cluster to clone.
- At the top of the Cluster Details page, click Clone.

In the dialog box, choose Yes to include the steps from the original cluster in the cloned cluster. Choose No to clone the original cluster's configuration without including any of the steps.

Note

For clusters created using AMI 3.1.1 and later (Hadoop 2.x) or AMI 2.4.8 and later (Hadoop 1.x), if you clone a cluster and include steps, all system steps (such as configuring Hive) are cloned along with user-submitted steps, up to 1,000 total. Any older steps that no longer appear in the console's step history cannot be cloned. For earlier AMIs, only 256 steps can be cloned (including system steps). For more information, see Submit Work to a Cluster.

- The Create Cluster page appears with a copy of the original cluster's
  configuration. Review the configuration, make any necessary changes,
  and then click Create Cluster.